# OpenCL autocorrelation kernel

Tags: opencl

I have written a simple program that does autocorrelation as follows...I've used pgi accelerator directives to move the computation to GPUs.

```
//autocorrelation
void autocorr(float *restrict A, float *restrict C, int N)
{
      int i, j;
      float sum;
      #pragma acc region
      {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                        sum = 0.0;
                for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    if ((i+j) < N)
                      sum += A[j] * A[i+j];
                    else
                      continue;
               }
            C[i] = sum;
       }
       }
}
```

I wrote a similar program in OpenCL, but I am not getting correct results. The program is as follows...I am new to GPU programming, so apart from hints that could fix my error, any other advices are welcome.

```
__kernel void autocorrel1D(__global double *Vol_IN, __global double *Vol_AUTOCORR, int size)
{

    int j, gid = get_global_id(0);
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if ((gid+j) < size)
            {
               sum += Vol_IN[j] * Vol_IN[gid+j];
            }
            else
               continue;
               }

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    Vol_AUTOCORR[gid] = sum;

}
```

Since I have passed the dimension to be 1, so I am considering my get_global_size(0) call would give me the id of the current block, which is used to access the input 1d array.

Thanks,
Sayan

Comment: What results are you getting? If you change `Vol_AUTOCORR[gid] = sum;` to `Vol_AUTOCORR[gid] = gid;`, does that give you the expected array of incremented values?

Comment: I do not see an issue here? What's your host code? Do you transfer the data correctly to the device and back?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...there isn't any issues with the kernel, I had a mistake in the host code, which caused the results to be awry. Thanks for evaluating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. As far as I know, that should run fine and give corret results.

**barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);** is not needed. You'll get more speed without that sentence.

Your problem should be outside the kernel, check that you a re passing correctly the input, and you are taking out of GPU the correct data.

BTW, I supose you are using a double precision suported GPU as you are doing double calcs.
Check that you are passing also double values. Remember you CAN't point a float pointer to a double value, and viceversa. That will give you wrong results.

Comment: Yes I noticed that the BARRIER is not required in this case. Thank you for pointing me to the datatype.