# OpenCL: Parallelize Lagged Vector Operation (Triangular distance matrix)

Tags: opencl, distance, distance-matrix

I'm having trouble creating a kernel for this serial code:

```
void distlag(double *x, double *y,double *data, double *ncoord, double *res)
{
    // x: x-coordinate
    // y: y-coordinate
    // data: value associated with x-y coordinate
    // ncoord: number of coordinates
    int i=0, j=0;
    double u=0.0, v=0.0, lags=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<(ncoord[0]-1);i++)
        for(j=(i+1); j<ncoord[0];j++)
        {
            // Pairwise distances
            lags=hypot(x[i]-x[j],y[i]-y[j]);
            u=data[i]; 
            v=data[j]; 
            *res+= u+v+lags;
        } 
    }
```

I think the main problem is that in `hypot`, distances depend on values in the same vector. Or, it may be that the `j` value depends on `i`. How can I parallel this code using OpenCL?

(More Info:)

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970410/opencl-autocorrelation-kernel), I started by trying to get upper triangular distance matrix values first. This is the kernel code:

```
__kernel void totexp(__global float *x, __global float *xauto, int n)
{
int num_wrk_items  = get_local_size(0);
int local_id       = get_local_id(0);
int group_id       = get_group_id(0);
int j, gid = get_global_id(0);
float sum = 0.0;


for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
{
if ( ((gid+j)!= j) && ((gid+j) < n)) 
       {
   sum = fabs(x[j]-x[gid+j]);
        }
        else
            continue;
  }
  xauto[gid] = sum;
}
```

`int n` is the `length` of `x` (x is equal to (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)). I should then have `n(n-1)/2` values (28 in total for the example). I set the global and local work sizes as `n` (8). The size of `cl_mem` buffer objects for `x` and `xauto` are `n` and `n(n-1)/2` (28) respectively. But when I read the results back I get 28 values but not the expected ones. I get: (0,7,12,15,16,15,12,7,0,0,0...,0). Any help?